# PHP CreateFromFromFormat() Month & Year Only

Tags: php, datetime, date-format, datetime-format, time-format

I am trying to create data from format using Datetime Class as following

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('m-Y', '02-2016');
echo $date->format('Y-m-d');
```

Out put 2016-03-01, i was expecting to get 2016-02-01

is it a bug? or i am understating this function in a wrong way?

Answer (score 3):

If you provide month and year, then PHP will provide a default day, using the current day of the current month (ie 30) today

That gives an effective 2016-02-30, which isn't a valid date..... but PHP allows these types of values where days is higher/lower than days in month, months are higher/lower than months in the year, and just increments/decrements to a valid date..... in this case, 1 additional day after the last day in month 2 or 2016 (29th February 2016) to give 1st March 2016

**EDIT**

[Reference for day/month overflow/underflow behaviour](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.date.php)

> **Note:**
>   It is possible to over- and underflow the dd and DD format. Day 0 means the last day of previous month, whereas overflows count into the next month. This makes "2008-08-00" equivalent to "2008-07-31" and "2008-06-31" equivalent to "2008-07-01" (June only has 30 days).
>   It is also possible to underflow the mm and MM formats with the value 0. A month value of 0 means December of the previous year. As example "2008-00-22" is equivalent to "2007-12-22".
>   If you combine the previous two facts and underflow both the day and the month, the following happens: "2008-00-00" first gets converted to "2007-12-00" which then gets converted to "2007-11-30". This also happens with the string "0000-00-00", which gets transformed into "-0001-11-30" (the year -1 in the ISO 8601 calendar, which is 2 BC in the proleptic Gregorian calendar).

Answer (score 0):

It's an [**known bug**](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php#109881)... or a documented feature, depending on how you look at it. See [**Mark Baker**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/324584/mark-baker)'s answer for more details.

---

### Workaround :

To get the date you expect, just add `01` to your input as a value for the day of the month.

```
$input = '02-2016';
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('d-m-Y', '01-' . $input);
echo $date->format('Y-m-d');

// OUTPUT : 2016-02-01
```

Comment: It's not a bug, it's a documented behaviour, which isn't the same thing

Comment: Simply because without providing a day and with ini settings how is PHPs datetime supposed to format that?  Mark's answer clears this up

Comment: @ash @MarkBaker Any sane, logical implementation of `DateTime::createFromFormat()` would determine `February` as the month with `'m-Y'` and `'02-2016'` as input. Just that fact that it's documented that this does not return the expected result in some edge cases doesn't disqualify it as a bug!

Comment: Since `DateTime` produces a timestamp accurate to the (milli)second, an input of {month-year} leaves *a loooot* of room for interpretation. There is no *correct* answer as such. As it happens, `DateTime` defaults to taking missing parts from the *current date*, instead of, say, defaulting to `1` or `0`. It *also* happens to support date rollover, which *is* an explicit feature, for simplified time math I believe. These two characteristics together get you this result. It's not unintentional. The bug here is feeding incomplete input and expecting a specific output.

Comment: @deceze : IMO, a sane, logical implementation of `DateTime::createFromFormat()` would take the first day of the month when the day of the month is omitted. IMO, using the current day of the current month is anything but a sane, logical implementation, especially when considering bizarre edge cases like the one mentioned in the OP (where the month returned is different from the month given). Then, again, this is PHP we're talking about. This sort of nonsense is precisely why the language has been dubbed [a fractal of bad design](https://eev.ee/blog/2012/04/09/php-a-fractal-of-bad-design/).

Comment: Oh, this is certainly very debatable and I'm inclined to agree. Still doesn't make it a *bug* per se, just a bad API design (albeit internally consistent) that leads to actual bugs in userland code.

Comment: @deceze : IMO, that's a matter or perspective/semantics. Hence, my changing `It's an known bug` to `It's an known bug... or a documented feature, depending on how you look at it.` at the beginning of my answer. After all, I don't think any of us knows for certain whether the author(s) of the code had the bizarre, unintuitive behavior mentioned in the OP in mind when he/she/they wrote the code for `DateTime::createFromFormat()`. Most likely, it's just sloppy coding and edge cases like those were overlooked.

Comment: @John I would think any slop in the code would have been fixed by now after many years of iterations... It's simply a bad idea for an API design, which overlooked such issues from the beginning; or expected userland programmers to take care of such issues from the beginning.

Comment: @deceze : PHP is one of the sloppiest programming languages around. It's filled with inconsistencies, redundancies and simply poor design choices... which is a logical consequence of [how the language started out](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YIGRXEzjE6c). Some would argue [that it's a bit misleading to even call PHP designed](https://www.quora.com/Is-PHP-a-badly-designed-programming-language), especally in the early days. And while some things definitely have improved compared with those early days, overall it's still a mess...

Comment: You absolutely don't need to convince me of that. I simply insist that there's a difference between a *bug* and *braindead design*... ;-)

Comment: @deceze : And I simply insist that the difference between both is sometimes (including the issue mentioned in the OP) purely semantic / subjective. Anyway, let's just agree to disagree on this one ;-)

Comment: @JohnSlegers Your points on PHP as accurate or even valid as they may be are irrelevant in the context of this question and your answer.  I tend to agree with @deceze in that, regardless of opinion the API is likely wrong to allow `DateTime::createFromFormat` but it does, and it's documented at which point you saying it's a bug is wrong terminology.  Your clear dislike towards PHP is likely why you refuse to agree with it being a design fault at least carry your pitch fork to the actual problem ~ Zend?

Comment: @ash : When a design flaw results in behavior as unintuitive and nonsensical as producing a `DateTime` for a date in `March` when `'m-Y'` and `'02-2016'` are the values if input parameters - **and only on certain days of the month** - I consider that a bug... You don't. Neither does @deceze. I get that. I respect that. I'm OK with that. Hence, my position that arguing over whether it's a bug or just a (very) poorly designed feature is a highly subjective discussion over semantics... which I generally consider pretty pointless.

Comment: @ash : `Your clear dislike towards PHP is likely why you refuse to agree with it being a design fault`  - Please don't mistake my acknowledgements of the flaws of PHP for a dislike towards PHP. I love programming in PHP! I love the fact that setting up a LAMP stack is so damn easy and cheap! I love the fact that PHP code is so easy to read for me (compared with eg. Ruby or Python)! etc. Just because I acknowledge the well-documented fact that PHP is in many ways poorly designed, that doesn't mean I hate the language... at all!

Comment: It's because I wanted to clarify the definition of "a bug" *(an error in a computer program or system)* which in your entitled opinion you disagree with.  Then you started referring to blogs about it's flaws - which we all know about but are irrelevant in this Q&A.